# DTD is Prohibited on internal DTD, even though validators say my XML and DTD is correct?

Tags: xml, dtd

The following is the code in my XML file, including the internal DTD which seems to be causing the issue.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" standalone = "yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE Movies[
    <!ELEMENT Movies (Movie)>
    <!ELEMENT Movie (title, Ratings, Age_Rating, Release_Date, cast)>
    <!ATTLIST Movie
    id CDATA #REQUIRED
    >
    <!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>  
    <!ELEMENT Ratings (IMD_Rating?, Rotten_Tomatoes?, Common_Sense_Media?)>
    <!ELEMENT IMD_Rating (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Rotten_Tomatoes (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Common_Sense_Media (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Age_Rating (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Release_Date (#PCDATA)>
    
    <!ELEMENT cast (actor)+>
    <!ELEMENT actor (#PCDATA)>
    
]>
<Movies>
    <Movie id = "1">
        <title>The Joker</title>
        <Ratings>
            <IMD_Rating>8.5/10</IMD_Rating>
            <Rotten_Tomatoes>68%</Rotten_Tomatoes>
            <Common_Sense_Media>4/5</Common_Sense_Media>
        </Ratings>
    
        <Age_Rating>15</Age_Rating>
        <Release_Date>2nd October 2019</Release_Date>
    
        <cast>  
            <actor>Joaquin Phoenix</actor>
            <actor>Robert De Niro</actor>
            <actor>Zazie Beetz</actor>
            <actor>Frances Conroy</actor>
            <actor>Brett Cullen</actor>
            <actor>Shea Whigham</actor>
            <actor>Bill Camp</actor>
            <actor>Glenn Fleshler</actor>
        </cast> 
    </Movie>    
</Movies>
```

[Image showing code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xMW8N.png)

As you can see in this image I'm getting an error message, however I can't work out why. Any`enter code here` help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed! In notepadd++ DTD is not allowed by default, so the fix was simply a settings change.